# Facebook sharing issue for a Link and a screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

When I only share a link, the link appears. When I only share an image, the image appears. However, when I want to do both with the code below, only the link appears, without the image.

Can I do both?

```
let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()

    if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, false, 0);
        window.drawViewHierarchyInRect(window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        let urlPath: String = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reflex-test!-how-far-can-you/id1123340346?ls=1&mt=8"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        composeSheet.addURL(url)
        composeSheet.addImage(image)

        presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried the same code it is working for me. At the same time I am able to share link as well as image.

Comment: @AshishVerma that is strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same code and it is working for me. Please find attached screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
let facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            facebookSheet.addImage(image)
            facebookSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.co.in"))
            self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for this response! I'll try that right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can **only** do things with the Facebook API, that you can do on the Facebook website.

You can't share a link and an image at the same time on the Facebook website.

That means, **you can't do that with the API** either.

But, you could add the link as the text of the post.